# cordova visual studio ios build

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova

Hello I am trying to build my app on Mac but always get same error.

> Error: An error occurred uploading to the build server
>   https://xxx.xxx.x.x:3000/cordova: Error: certificate is not yet
>   valid myAppp      1   Build

I wrote `remotebuild start` to command line on mac ant it is listening port 3000, What can I do to solve problem ?

Comment: Is your date and time correct?  What is the validity date of the certificate?

Comment: where is the validity date of the certificate written ?